# Alternative merge.conflictStyle values? (other than merge and diff3)

Tags: git

I've recently switched from the default **merge** to **diff3** and find the latter excellent, but couldn't find in documentation a full list of the existing styles, ideally with verbose descriptions.

diff3 seems nice and all, but knowing all tools at your disposal can't hurt, I guess.

Comment: `git help config` says that `merge.conflictStyle` has `merge` and `diff3`.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-mergeconflictStyle

Comment: To both of you : yes, these two values and the quoted git doc paragraph are exactly the starting point of my question. But there are usually so many options for git commands that I wrongfully assumed this couldn't be exhaustive...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are (currently, as of Git 2.18) only two valid conflict styles, `diff3` and `merge`.  This could change in the future, but it has not since Git 1.6.1 (when `merge.conflcitStyle` was introduced).  See function [`git_xmerge_config` in xdiff-interface.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3e5524907b43337e82a24afbc822078daf7a868f/xdiff-interface.c#L313-L328).